# Почему в .net core 2.0 нет интерфейса IMiddleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .netcore2.0

Я сейчас начал изучение .NET Core 2.0. Практически сразу рассматривается конвейер http и компоненты middleware. Изучаю по [этим статьям](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/). После прочтения:

> Класс middleware должен иметь конструктор, который принимает параметр типа RequestDelegate. Через этот параметр можно получить ссылку на тот делегат запроса, который стоит следующим в конвейере обработки запроса.
>
> Также в классе должен быть определен метод, который должен называться либо Invoke, либо InvokeAsync. Причем этот метод должен возвращать объект Task и принимать в качестве параметра контекст запроса - объект HttpContext. Данный метод собственно и будет обрабатывать запрос.

у меня возник вопрос: *почему бы просто не определить интерфейс для middleware компонентов, а не делать ограничения на уровне соглашения?*

Я уверен, что у разработчиков были веские причины на это. Но я бы хотел понять какие. Ведь сейчас, как я понимаю (возможно ошибаюсь), используется рефлексия, чтобы определить есть ли у типа объекта метод Invoke или InvokeAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все ради гибкости. Invoke позволяет объявить дополнительные параметры, значения которых будут разрезолвлены через DI:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx, 
                         IHostingEnvironment host,
                         ISomethingElse service)
{
    // ...
}
```

... а механизм интерфейсов не позволяет объявлять методы с заранее неизвестными параметрами.

[enSO: Why middleware in ASP.NET Core requires specific semantics, but not an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897781/why-middleware-in-asp-net-core-requires-specific-semantics-but-not-an-interface)